# Logstash, mongodb and jdbc

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I have a problem configuring logstash. I want to be able to put in input jdbc for mongodb.

My config :

```
input{
    jdbc{
        jdbc_driver_library => "mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mongodb.MongoClient"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017"
        jdbc_user => ""
    }
}
output{
    stdout{

    }
}
```

The problem is :

> :error=>"Java::JavaSql::SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/"}

Answer (score 2):

The MongoDB JDBC Driver setting is not correct. You must specify the name of the driver class, not the client class.

```
jdbc_driver_class => "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
```

Also make sure that the `jdbc_driver_library` contains the full absolute path to your `mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar` JAR file

Answer (score 0):

More inputs would be good. 
you must specify the location of the  **mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar** in jdbc_driver_library.

please see the following links : 
[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html)
[Similar problem](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/16)