# Logstash Configuration Error - jdbc_driver_library is not set

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

I am using Logstash to move data from my Microsoft SQL Server database to ElasticSearch. I receive the following error in the log files when I try to run logstash.
I run:

```
sudo -Hu logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash -t
```

Error:

```
  Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
  Stack: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:163:in `open_jdbc_connection'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:221:in `execute_statement'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:277:in `execute_query'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:263:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:309:in `inputworker'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:302:in `block in start_input'
[2019-09-18T00:16:36,250][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>[user_name], jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE delete_flag = 'N'", jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:sqlserver://[IP]:1433;databaseName=[database];", id=>"04af4c4719615e3a3a03c3df3e5262aa40c40e85fb55a5886a1797d42eb3a729", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_76e4bd7a-70dd-46cf-acd3-c3726a8e003f", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}, last_run_metadata_path=>"/usr/share/logstash/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not loaded. :jdbc_driver_library is not set, are you sure you included
                    the proper driver client libraries in your classpath?
```

I am running ElasticSearch/Logstash on an Ubuntu 18 server. I installed ElasticSearch, Logstash, Java 11, and downloaded the jdbc and placed it in the same folder as my logstash config.

My Logstash Config is:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://[my_ip]:1433;databaseName=[db_name];"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_user => "[username]"
    jdbc_password => "[password]"

    schedule => "0 4 * * * America/New_York"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE delete_flag = 'N'"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "products"
  }
}
```

I specified the jdbc driver library, not sure why I keep getting an error why logstash can't find it.

I also tried to run (below)

```
sudo bash -c "export CLASSPATH=.:/etc/logstash/conf.d/sqljdbc42.jar"
```

*Note: I took out some data, ip, dbname, username, etc.*

Comment: You need to set an absolute path to the library. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658663/logstash-mongodb-and-jdbc/43671901#43671901

Comment: @Val Updated to an absolute path but I still get the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure the process can read the `/etc/logstash/conf.d/` folder. Try to place the JAR in the Logstash folder instead

Comment: @Val Still the same error. after moving it to `/usr/share/logstash/`. Do you think it has to do with how I set the CLASSPATH?

Comment: echo ${CLASSPATH} returns `/usr/share/logstash/sqljdbc42.jar`, which is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been an issue with logstash-filter-jdbc_static for a while now. You need to move your .jar to /logstash-core/lib/jars/ directory. And specify the .jar location in your config as "".

See below for more details:
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-jdbc_static/issues/47